# ライトプロテクト機能付きUSBメモリのファイルオープンについて

Tags: linux, c

組み込みLinuxの環境でライトプロテクト付きUSBメモリ（バッファロ製、型番不明）について質問があります。
このメモリは、SWがついており、ライトプロテクトのON/OFFが出来ます。

このメモリをプロテクトONでマウントすると

```
mount: /dev/sda1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

とメッセージがデますがマウントできます。
この状態で、以下の様にファイルをリード属性でオープンするとエラーになります。

```
fp = fopen("/mdeia/usb/test.txt","r");
```

オープンすると、エラーになり、errno=2が帰ってきます。
コマンドラインからマニュアルでマウントし、catでファイル内容を表示しても問題ありません。

プロテクトOFFでは、正常にオープン出来ます。

`ls -al` ファイル属性を見ても、プロテクトON/OFFでは差がありません。

プロテクトONでは、`fopen()`でオープン出来無いのでしょうか？

---

```
fd = open("/media/usb/test.txt", O_RDONLY);
```

も試して見ました。やはり`fopen()`と同じでプロテクトONでは-1が返り、プロテクトOFFではオープン出来ました。

Comment: 「errno=2が帰ってきます」とのことですが、これは `OS error code   2:  No such file or directory` を意味します。ファイル名が `/mdeia/usb/test.txt` となっていますが、もしかして `/media/...` の間違いではないでしょうか？

Comment: すいません、質問のタイプミスです。プロテクトSWをOFFにすると正常に読めていますので、文法的には間違えていないと思います。ライトプロテクトがかかっていても、読込は出来ると思っているのですが、何故かファイルが見つかりません。

Comment: USBメモリのファイルシステムは何ですか？FATでしょうか？NTFS？それ以外？

Comment: FAT32です。mountの際は、vfatを指定しています。

Comment: `fopen()` でエラーが出る状態で、`open()` だとどうなるのでしょうか?

Comment: fd = open("/media/usb/test.txt", O_RDONLY) で試して見ました。やはりfopen()と同じでプロテクトONでは-1が返り、プロテクトOFFではオープン出来ました。

Comment: @Yoshi では更に、`opendir("/")`, `opendir("/media")`, `opendir("/media/usb")` して、それぞれについて `readdir()` して、どのように見えているか確認してみるのはいかがでしょうか? protect on でも cat なら問題ないとのことですので、きっと ls でも問題ないのだろうと(勝手に)思っています。ls の結果と、protect on 時の `readdir()` の結果と、protect off 時の `readdir()` の結果とを照らし合わせるなどして、何か気づければと思います。

Comment: USBメモリを明示的にリードオンリー(`-o ro`オプション指定)でマウントしたら、どうなりますか?

Answer (score 1):

[GNU cat](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/plain/src/cat.c) のソースを見てみました。

オプションなしの場合は `O_RDWR | O_BINARY` で読み込んでるようですので 試してみると良いかもしれません。

```
  if (! (number || show_ends || squeeze_blank))
    {
      file_open_mode |= O_BINARY;
      xset_binary_mode (STDOUT_FILENO, O_BINARY);
    }

  /* Check if any of the input files are the same as the output file.  */

  /* Main loop.  */

  infile = "-";
  argind = optind;

  do
    {
      if (argind < argc)
        infile = argv[argind];

      if (STREQ (infile, "-"))
        {
          have_read_stdin = true;
          input_desc = STDIN_FILENO;
          if (file_open_mode & O_BINARY)
            xset_binary_mode (STDIN_FILENO, O_BINARY);
        }
      else
        {
          input_desc = open (infile, file_open_mode);
          if (input_desc < 0)
            {
              error (0, errno, "%s", quotef (infile));
              ok = false;
              continue;
            }
        }
```